# Canvas - IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, canvas

So in Firefox I'm getting this error in the console when using drawImage on a canvas element.

```
"IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"
```

Everything is working fine in Chrome. Common causes for this I found were returning negative values or trying to draw the image to the canvas before the image is actually loaded. Neither of which seem to be the case. What am I missing here?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/Ra9KQ/3/

```
var NameSpace = NameSpace || {};

NameSpace.Pixelator = (function() {

    var _cache = {
        'wrapper' : null,
        'canvas'  : null,
        'ctx'     : null,
        'img'     : new Image()
    },

    _config = {
        'canvasWidth'      : 250,
        'canvasHeight'     : 250,
        'isPlaying'        : false,
        'distortMin'       : 3,
        'distortMax'       : 100,
        'distortValue'     : 100, // matches distortMax by default
        'initDistortValue' : 3,
        'speed'            : 2.5,
        'delta'            : 2.5,   // delta (+/- step), matches speed by default
        'animation'        : null,
        'origImgWidth'     : null,
        'origImgHeight'    : null,
        'imgHeightRatio'   : null,
        'imgWidthRatio'    : null,
        'newImgWidth'      : null,
        'newImgHeight'     : null
    },

    _init = function _init() {

        _setupCache();
        _setupCanvas();
        _setupImage();

    },

    _setupCache = function _setupCache() {

        _cache.wrapper = $('#dummy-wrapper');
        _cache.canvas = document.getElementById('dummy-canvas');
        _cache.ctx = _cache.canvas.getContext('2d');

    },

    _setupCanvas = function _setupCanvas() {

        _cache.ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        _cache.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        _cache.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    },

    _setupImage = function _setupImage() {

        _cache.img.onload = function() {

            _adjustImageScale();
            _pixelate();
            _assignEvents();

        };

        _cache.img.src = _cache.canvas.getAttribute('data-src');

    },

    _adjustImageScale = function _adjustImageScale() {

        var scaledHeight,
            scaledWidth;

        _config.origImgWidth = _cache.img.width;
        _config.origImgHeight = _cache.img.height;
        _config.imgHeightRatio = _config.origImgHeight / _config.origImgWidth;
        _config.imgWidthRatio = _config.origImgWidth / _config.origImgHeight;

        scaledHeight = Math.round(250 * _config.imgHeightRatio);
        scaledWidth = Math.round(250 * _config.imgWidthRatio);

        if (scaledHeight < 250) {

            _config.newImgHeight = 250;
            _config.newImgWidth = Math.round(_config.newImgHeight * _config.imgWidthRatio);

        } else if (scaledWidth < 250) {

            _config.newImgWidth = 250;
            _config.newImgHeight = Math.round(_config.newImgWidth * _config.imgHeightRatio);

        }

    },

    _assignEvents = function _assignEvents() {

        _cache.wrapper.on('mouseenter', _mouseEnterHandler);
        _cache.wrapper.on('mouseleave', _mouseLeaveHandler);

    },

    _mouseEnterHandler = function _mouseEnterHandler(e) {

        _config.delta = -_config.speed;

        if (_config.isPlaying === false) {
            _config.isPlaying = true;
            _animate();
        }

    },

    _mouseLeaveHandler = function _mouseLeaveHandler(e) {

        _config.delta = _config.speed;

        if (_config.isPlaying === false) {
            _config.isPlaying = true;
            _animate();
        }

    },

    _pixelate = function _pixelate(val) {

        var size = val ? val * 0.01 : 1,
            w = Math.ceil(_config.newImgWidth * size),
            h = Math.ceil(_config.newImgHeight * size);

        console.log('w: ' + w,'h: ' + h,'_config.newImgWidth: ' + _config.newImgWidth,'_config.newImgHeight: ' + _config.newImgHeight);

        _cache.ctx.drawImage(_cache.img, 0, 0, w, h);

        _cache.ctx.drawImage(_cache.canvas, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, _config.canvasWidth, _config.canvasHeight);

    },

    _animate = function _animate() {

        // increase/decrese with delta set by mouse over/out
        _config.distortValue += _config.delta;

        if (_config.distortValue >= _config.distortMax || _config.distortValue <= _config.distortMin) {

            _config.isPlaying = false;
            cancelAnimationFrame(_config.animation);
            return;

        } else {

            // pixelate
            _pixelate(_config.distortValue);
            _config.animation = requestAnimationFrame(_animate);

        }

    };

    return {
        init: _init
    };

})();

NameSpace.Pixelator.init();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you are using clipping you need to make sure that the source region is within the image (not necessary for target as this will be clipped by canvas).

So if you add restriction control it should work. Here is one way of doing this (before using the clipping functionality of `drawImage`):

```
if (w > _config.canvasWidth) w = _config.canvasWidth;
if (h > _config.canvasHeight) h = _config.canvasHeight;

_cache.ctx.drawImage(_cache.canvas, 0, 0, w, h,
                      0, 0, _config.canvasWidth, _config.canvasHeight);
```

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Ra9KQ/4/)**.

Tip 1:
Normally this also applies to x and y but as these are 0 here there is no need to check.

Tip 2:
If you need the image to be drawn narrower than you need to instead of changing source region, change the target region.

Comment: Perfect! Ken to the rescue again!

Comment: To clarify as well. Applying Math.round on the variables used in .drawImage() fixed this issue for me. Seems Firefox didn't like a fractioned number.

Comment: You probably had value between 0.5 and 1.0, that did rounded it to 1, while Firefox would `floor` it so it would be 0 - which triggers that issue. As floating numbers - are fine (tested).

Comment: The fiddle link doesn't work. Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra9KQ/4/).

Answer (score 9):

**Width** and **Height** of image you draw when you specify size values **should be larger or equal to 1**. As well for performance advantages `floor` all values you pass to it.
If width and/or height is 0, it will result in:

```
IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
```

In Firefox:

```
width = Math.max(1, Math.floor(width));
height = Math.max(1, Math.floor(height));
ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: don't you mean Math.max? This will result in the width and height always being 1 if the width or height are positive.

Comment: @Tails indeed, funny that noone has noticed it for such long time.

Answer (score 1):

To help others, I had the same problem in canvas and I solve taking account on image load, for example :

```
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "use-credentials";
image.onload = function(){
    // here canvas behavior
};
image.src = imgSrc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in **IE** and **Safari**. There were three things in particular that I had to fix:

1) I had to set the `width` and `height` of the image manually.

```
var image = new Image();
...
image.width = 34;
image.height = 34;
```

2) I had to avoid using negative offset when creating `ol.style.Icon`. In this case I had to change my SVG icon, but that pretty much depends to your icon. So this would cause exception because of the negative offset:

```
var icon = new ol.style.Style({
    "image": new ol.style.Icon({
        ...
        "offset": [0, -50]
    })
});
```

3) I had to *round* the width and height values. As some of them were calculated dynamically, I had values like `34.378` which were causing problems. So I had to round them and pass the *Integer* value.