# context.drawImage working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

So for some reason my javascript code for displaying images only works in Chrome, and not in any other browsers.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLy42oa0/

```js
 var snowflakeImage = new Image('');
    snowflakeImage.ready = true;
    snowflakeImage.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/W0rqcLP.png';  

function drawSnowflakes() {
        for(var i = 0; i < snowflakesInAir.length; i++) {
            //Failsafe
            if(snowflakesInAir[i].x > canvas.width || snowflakesInAir[i].y > canvas.height) {
                i++;
            }
                context.drawImage(snowflakeImage, snowflakesInAir[i].x, snowflakesInAir[i].y);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!
I've tried swapping to image.onload() however that seems to break in my gameLoop. Thanks!

Comment: No need to be mysterious: what specifically does not work in browsers other than Chrome?

Comment: Also, your JSFiddle worked fine in Chrome for me, but your SO snippet did not; the results were just blank - FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the resulted error in FireFox:

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed
>   amount

, and you can find a solution for your issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338032/canvas-indexsizeerror-index-or-size-is-negative-or-greater-than-the-allowed-a) , also :

> To clarify as well. Applying Math.round on the variables used in
>   .drawImage() fixed this issue for me. Seems Firefox didn't like a
>   fractioned number. –  Justin Beaudry

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much! It also led me to finding firebug, which is a excellent tool. The fix was adding one to the sWidth and x under the context.DrawImage call in the function drawBins().

Comment: @Siphorus glad i could help , if you find my answer correct , then please choose it as correct one :)