# DropzoneJS - IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, firefox, dropzone.js, drawimage

I started using [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) that is a great open source library with  [7,043](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/stargazers)  [stars](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/) on [Github](https://github.com/). It provides drag and drop file uploads with image previews.

However uploading images bigger than 100k resulted in the following error in `Firefox`:

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

in *dropzone.js* that was raised in the following line:

```
return ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh / vertSquashRatio);
```

Others have reported experiencing this behavior for thumbnails creation [here](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/686).

This is a common error in Firefox after a bit of research. Most relevant stackoverflow question:

1- [Canvas - IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338032/canvas-indexsizeerror-index-or-size-is-negative-or-greater-than-the-allowed-a)

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem after following this quick [fix](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/686).

Basically replaced:

```
return ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh / vertSquashRatio);
```

With:

```
return ctx.drawImage(img, Math.round(sx), Math.round(sy), Math.round(sw), Math.round(sh), Math.round(dx), Math.round(dy), Math.round(dw), Math.round(dh) / vertSquashRatio);
```

in my `dropzone.js`

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks we got the exact same issue today and your fix worked a treat ^^

Comment: Glad to hear @SubstanceD