# Facedetection.js IndexSIzeError in Mozila and Safari

Tags: jquery, face-detection

I'm trying to detect faces in images. I only need the number of faces in the image chosen by the user. I'm using the following code to load the image from the input field into a preview div:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var image = new FileReader();

        image.onloadend = function (e) {
            $('#image-wrap').html('<img src="" id="uploaded-photo">');                  
            $('#uploaded-photo').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#uploaded-photo').fadeIn();
            facedetect();
        }

        image.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#userfile").change(function() {      
    readURL(this);
});
```

The function for detection is this one

```
function facedetect() {
    $('#uploaded-photo').faceDetection({
        complete: function (faces) { 
            console.log(faces);
        },
        error: function (code, message) {
           console.log(message);
        }
    });
}
```

This is working just fine in Chrome, but on some occasions (although not all) in Mozilla and Safari, I get this in the console:

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

The line generating this seems to be this one:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you link to the documentation or github page for the face detection library you use.

Comment: first, thank you ! https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection

Comment: Given that the error only occurs sporadically I'd suggest it's an issue within the library which only happens when the image provided to it has some pattern within it. It may be worth contacting the library author about the issue, providing an image which causes the error.

Comment: i found a similar problem, but cant figure it out how to adapt the solution to my function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338032/canvas-indexsizeerror-index-or-size-is-negative-or-greater-than-the-allowed-a

Comment: seems that my image wasn't fully loaded so calling facedetect in load event solved the problem   $('#uploaded-photo').on('load',function(){
    facedetect();
          });

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. You should add that solution as an answer below to help anyone else who has the problem in the future

Answer (score 0):

seems that my image wasn't fully loaded so calling facedetect in load event solved the problem

```
$('#uploaded-photo').on('load',function(){ facedetect(); });
```

tx to all for trying to help me :)